# Why I got 'MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to 127.0.0.1:41067 closed' in running my test in github actions?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs, github-actions

I have created integration test for my backend service called **payments** . It is passing successfully in local but when I push it to github action and run the tests there, my test failing with error **MongoNetworkError: connection 3 to 127.0.0.1:41067 closed**. I am using **mongodb-memory-server** for in-memory db. I checked if I did not awaited some functions. And also checked my test setup.

My other services tests setup created in the same way and the test pass like in the local.  And I also if I missed any secret.

Here the picture of the error in github action

[image]

This is my yml file related

```js
name: tests-payments
on: pull_request
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      STRIPE_KEY: ${{ secrets.STRIPE_KEY }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: cd payments && npm install && npm run test:ci
```

I want to add also related repo also for showing the test that fails

https://github.com/sayinmehmet47/ticketing-with-client/blob/master/payments/src/events/listener/__test__/order-created-listener.test.ts